# How to solve error: Cannot find module "dns" at webpackMissingModule in Ionic 3

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3, nodemailer

I am trying to implement `nodemailer` into my **ionic 3** project, and I followed the tutorial from codeburst.io (https://codeburst.io/sending-an-email-using-nodemailer-gmail-7cfa0712a799).

When I followed the tutorial and did an ionic serve, there is an error for 'Cannot find module "dns"'. The image below shows the error in my console.

[image: Error message]

Here are the codes in my .ts file:

```
constructor(){
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
     service: 'gmail',
     auth: {
       user: 'XXXXX@gmail.com',
       pass: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
     }
   });
   const mailOptions = {
     from: 'XXXXXXX@email.com', // sender address
     to: 'XXXXXXXXX@email.com', // list of receivers
     subject: 'Subject of your email', // Subject line
     html: '<p>Your html here</p>'// plain text body
   };

   transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (err, info) {
     if(err)
       console.log(err)
     else
       console.log(info);
  });

 }
```

I have tried searching but I couldn't find a solution for Ionic with Angular typescript. I am new to the concept of DNS so some guidelines/explanation is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I have figured it out! I added a `dns: 'empty'` in my webpack.config file.

The code will look something like this:

```
node: {
  dns: 'empty'
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it